# How to define EF Many To Many Relationship in type that has other relationships to the same other type

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

This is quite a simple problem that has quite a long explanation so please bear with me if this gets long. (i'm really going to try and keep it to a minimum)

Ok so here's my "extracted sample" that produces the same problem ...

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TypeA> TypeAs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TypeB> TypeBees { get; set; }
}

public class TypeA
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SpecialBId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TypeB> Bees { get; set; }

    public virtual TypeB SpecialB { get; set; }
}

public class TypeB
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TypeA> Aaas { get; set; }
}
```

... so I enable EF Migrations, run add migration, run update database and I get this ...

[image]

What I would expect to see is a join table for the many to many, but for some reason that second "SpecialB" reference causes this to break the many to many reference / redefine it somehow.

So I figured uh ok ... maybe it just needs a hand so I added an onmodel create to my context ...

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TypeA>().HasMany<TypeB>(i => i.Bees);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TypeB>().HasMany<TypeA>(i => i.Aaas);
    }
```

Generation of a migration at this point produces nothing.

> So, how do I get these relationships to work
>   correctly and produce the correct db structure?

Just in case ...

This is what Ef generates when running add-migration to create an initial migration for the db context above with the types as defined:

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TypeAs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    SpecialBId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.TypeBs", t => t.SpecialBId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.SpecialBId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.TypeBs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    TypeA_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.TypeAs", t => t.TypeA_Id)
            .Index(t => t.TypeA_Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.TypeAs", "SpecialBId", "dbo.TypeBs");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.TypeBs", "TypeA_Id", "dbo.TypeAs");
        DropIndex("dbo.TypeBs", new[] { "TypeA_Id" });
        DropIndex("dbo.TypeAs", new[] { "SpecialBId" });
        DropTable("dbo.TypeBs");
        DropTable("dbo.TypeAs");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add WithMany():

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TypeA>().HasMany<TypeB>(i => i.Bees).WithMany();
modelBuilder.Entity<TypeB>().HasMany<TypeA>(i => i.Aaas).WithMany();
```